# There are no addresses available for this application

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-addin

I have the following script to create the subscription settings service application but I get this error:

There are no addresses available for this application

```
#This service application provides multi-tenancy features as well as the ability to run apps.
#Read more: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp161236.aspx
$ServiceApplicationName = "Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Subscription Settings Service Application"
$ServiceName = "Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Subscription Settings Service"
$MachinesToActivate = @("PRJSERV")
$DatabaseName = "spServiceApp-Subscription"
$spAppPoolName = "Subscription Settings Service Application Pool Account"
$spAppPoolAcc = "PRJSERV\spAppPool"
$AppDomain = "prjserv-apps.local"
$AppPrefix = "app"

Write-Host "SharePoint 2013 - '$ServiceApplicationName'..."

#Allows to use SharePoint cmdlets from inside the Windows PowerShell command window
Add-PsSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Out-Null
Start-SPAssignment -Global | Out-Null

#Get default SQL server
$DatabaseServer = (Get-SPDatabase | ? { $_.Type -eq "Configuration Database" }).NormalizedDataSource

try
{
    #Check for existing service application and proxy
    $ExistingServiceApp = Get-SPServiceApplication | where-object {$_.Name -eq $ServiceApplicationName}

    if ($ExistingServiceApp -eq $null)
    {
        Write-Host " - Creating '$ServiceApplicationName'"

        #Check if application pool already exist, if not create it
        $spManagedAccount = Get-SPManagedAccount -Identity $spAppPoolAcc
        $ApplicationPool = Get-SPServiceApplicationPool -Identity $spAppPoolName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
        if ($ApplicationPool -eq $null)
        {
            New-SPServiceApplicationPool -Name $spAppPoolName -Account $spManagedAccount | Out-Null
        }
        else
        {
            Set-SPServiceApplicationPool $ApplicationPool -Account $spManagedAccount | Out-Null
        }        

        $SA = New-SPSubscriptionSettingsServiceApplication -Name $ServiceApplicationName -ApplicationPool $spAppPoolName -DatabaseServer $DatabaseServer -DatabaseName $DatabaseName

        #Create Service Application Proxy
        Write-Host " - Creating '$ServiceApplicationName' proxy"
        New-SPSubscriptionSettingsServiceApplicationProxy -ServiceApplication $SA | Out-Null

        #Start service instances
        Write-Host " - Starting service instance"
        foreach ($machine in $MachinesToActivate) 
        {
            #Gets the service to determine its status
            $service = $(Get-SPServiceInstance | where {$_.TypeName -match $ServiceName} | where {$_.Server -match "SPServer Name="+$machine})

            If ($service.Status -eq "Disabled") 
            {
                Write-Host " - Starting" $service.ID "on $machine"
                Start-SPServiceInstance -Identity $service.ID | Out-Null
            }
        }

        #Setting App Management Properties
        Write-Host " - Setting App Management Properties"             
        Set-SPAppDomain -appdomain $AppDomain
        Set-SPAppSiteSubscriptionName -Name $AppPrefix -Confirm:$false

        Write-Host " - Done creating '$ServiceApplicationName'.`n"
    }
    else 
    {
        #Write-Host " - '$ServiceApplicationName' already exists."
        write-host " - Removing '$ServiceApplicationName'..."
        Remove-SPServiceApplication $ExistingServiceApp -removedata -Confirm:$false

        #Proxy is NOT automatically deleted
        $ExistingServiceAppProxy = Get-SPServiceApplicationProxy | where-object {$_.Name -eq "$ServiceApplicationName Proxy"}
        if ($ExistingServiceAppProxy -ne $null)
        {
            write-host " - Removing '$ServiceApplicationName proxy'..."
            Remove-SPServiceApplicationProxy $ExistingServiceAppProxy -Confirm:$false
        }
        write-host " - Stopping service instance..."
        Get-SPServiceInstance | where-object {$_.TypeName -eq $ServiceName} | Stop-SPServiceInstance -Confirm:$false | Out-Null
    }
}
catch { write-Output $_ }

Stop-SPAssignment -Global | Out-Null
```

I also have in the host file this:

127.0.0.1 prjserv-apps.local

Comment: at what stage you getting this error? on what line of the code it is throwing?

Comment: on this one  Set-SPAppSiteSubscriptionName -Name $AppPrefix -Confirm:$false

Comment: is the subscription and app services is running? check from service on server via CENTRAL ADMIN

Comment: they werent, but I started them and ran the script again with the same output